# I want to parameterize the filename textfield of CSV dataset config

Tags: jmeter

I want to parameterize the filename textfield of CSV dataset config from other CSV dataset config.

### Here is my test plan

```
Test Plan
 CSV Config1-file1
 Login
 LoopController
   CSV config2-file2
   Upload files
```

Users will login and upload the files(Every user need to upload different files)

file1 will have username,file path. CSV config2 'Filename' has to pick from 'file1'

I tried but ${csvFilename} in the filename option of CSV dataset config element,but jmeter is not evaluating the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your `CSV config2-file2` **as a child** of `Upload files`.

You also need to provide full paths to your files either in CSV or in "Send Files With The Request" input.

References:

- [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)
- [How to Performance Test Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache Jmeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)

Comment: Hi Dimitri,Issue is not resolved when CSV config2-file2 as a child of Upload files,details of CSV files  
CSV Config1-file1:- user1,d:\user1file.txt
                    user2,d:\user2file.txt
CSV Config2-file2:- for user1 the 'filename' should be d:\user1file.txt
                    for user2 the 'filename' should be d:\user2file.txt
user1file.txt:-  d:\user1upload1.xlsx
                 d:\user1upload2.xlsx          
'user1file.txt' will have the path of files to be uploaded,In 'CSV config2-file2' we have to use a variable like 'filetoupload' whose value should be picked from 'user1file.txt'

Comment: If so there is a JMeter function called __threadnum - https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum which stands for thread number starting from 1, so your variable should look like `d:\user${__threadNum}file.txt`. This way you'll get user1file.txt for 1st thread, user2file.txt for second, etc. Apologies for misunderstanding your initial request.

Comment: Hi Dimitri,I need to execute the testplan multiple iterations in that case {_threadNum} wont be in our control,let me know how to handle this